# Client not connecting to port running openssl s_server

Tags: networking, port, openssl

Question Context:
I want to test a TLS handshake and see all the output (for learning/work related purposes) between my local computer (running OSX Yosemite) and a remote work server (running amazon ec2 linux instance)
I am running

```
   `openssl s_server -cert /etc/ssl/certs/test.pem -msg`
```

on the work server. According to the openssl docs on s_server, this runs an ssl/tls server on port 4433. I can confirm by running:

`sudo netstat -tulpn`

I get the following line which confirms that the port is open:

`tcp    0  0 0.0.0.0:4433    0.0.0.0:*  LISTEN      9215/openssl`

Now, from my local computer I run:

`openssl s_client -tls1 -cert <client_cert> -msg -connect <serverHost>:4433 -state -debug` and it does not connect to the openssl service running on port 4433 (i.e. they do not start the handshake with the hello messages). The connection times out with :

`connect: Operation timed out
connect:errno=60`

This is is pretty confusing. Why would it not connect to port 4433 on the work server?

Comment: Looks like your `serverHost` is blocking port 4433. Try `timeout 1 bash -c 'cat < /dev/null > /dev/tcp/serverHost/4433' && echo "port is blocked" || echo "port is blocked"`

Comment: Hmm. There is no tcp directory in /dev on my version of linux.

Comment: Also running nmap does not list port 4433.

Comment: Once you solve the network-level problem, `s_client` will only send-and-use a client cert-and-key if the server requests client authentication, and `s_server` will only do that if you specify `-verify n` or `-Verify n`. Also both will get and display verification errors unless you specify `-CAfile` and/or `-CApath` with appropriate data set up, but if you only want the debug output those verification errors don't matter.

Comment: Yeah, I originally stripped it I guess. I have the full version of the commands right down. I guess what I am having problems is with the network. s_client times out.

Comment: For the record, /dev/tcp is not a real directory. From man bash: /dev/tcp/host/port
                     If host is a valid hostname or Internet address, and port is an integer port number or service name, bash attempts to open a TCP connection to the corresponding socket.